# Y-style task execution

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have Task, Task1 and Task2. Task1 and Task2 are independent from each other, but both depend on the result of Task. I can make it work this way:

```
static async Task Test1()
{
    var task = Task.Delay(1000);

    var task1 = task.ContinueWith(_ => 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task1, thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    });

    var task2 = task.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task2, thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```

Or, alternatively, this way:

```
static async Task Test2()
{
    var task = Task.Delay(1000);
    await task;

    var task1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task1, thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    });

    var task2 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task2, thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```

Which way should I prefer? Are they both equally efficient? Is there a better way of composing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a better way of composing this would be to create separate `async` methods for the follow-up `Task`s. Something like:

```
private static async Task Task1(Task task)
{
    await task;
    Console.WriteLine("Task1, thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}

private static async Task Task2(Task task)
{
    await task;
    Console.WriteLine("Task2, thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}

private static async Task Test1()
{
    var task = Task.Delay(1000);

    var task1 = Task1(task);
    var task2 = Task2(task);

    await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
}
```

This will act differently than your code with regard to synchronization context (if one is present), but you can affect that by using `await task.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: I must be missing something but total duration is `t+t1+t2` in this code (when I run on my computer). On the other hand it is `t+max(t1,t2)` in OP's cases.

Comment: @I4V How do you measure the duration? If you use something like `Thread.Sleep()` and you run this on the UI thread, then yeah, that's what's going to happen. But if `task1` and `task2` were actually asynchronous, you would get the expected behavior. I mentioned that when synchronization context comes into play, this behaves differently than the original code.

Comment: Even in Console application I see the same effect.

Comment: @I4V Then you must have put the `Thread.Sleep()` before the `await`. In general, you shouldn't do significant synchronous work in `async` methods. If you do have that and you want to execute two such `Task`s in parallel, then you should use `Task.Run()`. But I don't see any indication that's what's actually needed in this question.

Comment: `private static async Task Task1(Task task)
        {
            await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Task1, thread: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }` and same for other method...

Comment: @I4V You're right and I certainly did not expect that. It seems that when both methods are waiting on the same `Task`, they are resumed on the same thread. But like I said before, if you want to execute two methods with significant synchronous work in parallel, use `Task.Run()` on them.

Comment: I'll choose OP's first alternative.

Comment: @I4V, for svick's solution I measured timing like this: http://pastebin.com/JwvFjkxM. I believe it still does exactly what I need, and the timing I see is `t+max(t1,t2)` (3500ms), not `t+t1+t2`. Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is really not an answer, just another alternative

```
var task = Task.Delay(1000);
await task.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => {
                Console.WriteLine("Task1, thread: {0}",Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            },
            () => {
                Console.WriteLine("Task2, thread: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            });
    });
```